# Validation of Tag length

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-taggable-on

For acts-as-taggable-on, how do you make Tags be a certain amount of characters? I want users to only be able to have a maximum of 50 characters when they are creating tags.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a validation for this. Try using this in your model. Replace  `:tag_name` with the correct field.

```
validates_length_of :tag_name, :maximum=>50
```

Also an awesome [reference to rails validations](http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#M000084) is here.